# Cobertura Report using JUnit

Tags: java

I am using JUnit for unit testing but somehow the test is not covered by the Cobertura report. I am not exactly sure what am i doing wrong.

I am testing the following method:

```
public List<LocateIPAddressServiceRequestParameter> getLocateIPAddressServiceRequestParameters(String ipAddress) {
    List<LocateIPAddressServiceRequestParameter> findParams = new ArrayList<LocateIPAddressServiceRequestParameter>();

    if (ipAddress != null) {
        findParams
                .add(new LocateIPAddressServiceRequestParameter(
                        LocateIPAddressServiceRequestParameter.PARAMETERS.ipAddress,
                        ipAddress));
    }

    return findParams;
}
```

That's my JUnit test:

```
@Test
public void testGetLocateIPAddressServiceRequestParameters() throws EISClientException, Exception {
    String ipAddress = null;

    EISThirdPartyClient client = new EISThirdPartyClient(new ClientConfiguration(), "test");
    List<LocateIPAddressServiceRequestParameter> parameter = client.getLocateIPAddressServiceRequestParameters(ipAddress);

    for (LocateIPAddressServiceRequestParameter params : parameter) {
        if (params.key == LocateIPAddressServiceRequestParameter.PARAMETERS.ipAddress) {
            ipAddress = params.value;
            fail("Parameter is null");
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone let me know what am I doing wrong and why it is not covered by the Cobertura report.
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

The second line of your method checks if `ipAddress` is null, while the test will pass `null` as the parameter.

JVM might be doing some optimizations... Write another test, when `ipAddress` is not `null` and compare.